# What am I missing with this recursion call? (dynamic programing)

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

Im going over the solution to a previous midterm of mine below, and i dont understand line 9 in the pseudo code. For the first iteration when s=1 and i=1, A[i] would equal 12, whixh would make C[i,s] equal to C[i-1,s]

But wouldnt C[i-1,s] throw an error since i would now be 0 (out of bounds?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 9:

```
C[i,s] = C[i-1,s].
```

Note that in subproblem `c` you have already defined:

```
C[0,s] = 0 for all s.
```

So `C[1-1, s]` will return a `0`.